# Cannot convert from Foo<F> to F?

Tags: c#, generics

I'm using a **CRTP-style** generic construct in C#, and have these classes:

```
public abstract class Foo<F> where F : Foo<F>
{ 
    public abstract Bar<F> Bar { get; }

    public void Baz()
    {
        return this.Bar.Qux(this); //Error is here: "Argument 1: Cannot convert from 'Foo<F>' to 'F'
    }
}

public abstract class Bar<F> where F : Foo<F>
{
    public abstract void Qux(F foo);
}
```

This seems very strange to me, considering `this` should always be a Foo, right?

Comment: 'this' is a instance of Foo<F> and you're try to pass it to Qux, which should accept F. So message is absolutely correct. What you try to do is casting List<string> to string (as example)

Comment: The compiler won't accept `this` alone because it is not certain that it will be of type `F`. This is because the provided generic constraint enforces `F` to be a subclass of `Foo<F>` but not the opposite; for that reason you can declare any class subclassing `Foo<>` but specifying a different class as generic parameter, like in `class X : Foo<X> {} class G : Foo<X> {}` where `G` is `Foo<X>` but is not `X`.

Comment: I've submitted a proposal issue to the Roslyn compiler team to add an F-Bound / CRTP generic type constraint.  If you are interested in seeing this functionality added to the language, please comment on the issue.  Here is the link: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/4332

Comment: Very nice, @tyree-jackson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that context, `this` is a `Foo<F>`. The argument of Qux is declared as `F`. It needs to be changed to `Foo<F>`:

```
  public abstract class Foo<F> where F : Foo<F> {

    public abstract Bar<F> Bar { get; }

    public void Baz() {
      Bar.Qux(this);
    }

  }

  public abstract class Bar<F> where F : Foo<F> {

    public abstract void Qux(Foo<F> foo);

  }
```

Comment: Ah, I see. Is there a reason my logic is flawed that it could be able to figure out that `this` is an `F`, or does the compiler just not try?

Comment: `this` is an instance of the class. The class is `Foo<F>`, not `F`.