# Base generic class with automatic T from inherited son type

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I've a situation like this

```
abstract class Foo<T>
{
    // Implementation using T type...
}
class Bar : Foo<Bar>
{ }
```

Every class that inherits from Foo uses itself as generic Type, and I have various inherited classes, ex: "Bar1", "Bar2", etc...

Is possible to implement the Foo class taking automatically the generic type from the inherited class type?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to *constrain* `T` so that every inheritor is a `Foo<T>` then you can do:

```
abstract class Foo<T> where T:Foo<T>
{
    // Implementation using T type...
}
class Bar : Foo<Bar>
{ }
```

Note that it's not 100% guaranteed that any class `S` inheriting from `Foo` is a `Foo<S>` because you can still do:

```
class Quux : Foo<Bar>
{ }
```

Which still satisfies the generic constraint because `Bar` is a `Foo<Bar>`, however `Quux` is *not* a `Foo<Quux>`

Comment: he worded it poorly but I think you nailed it

Comment: +1 for this answer.  However, beware of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31771282/cannot-convert-from-foof-to-f#comment51562976_31771282 issue.  If the author is trying to guarantee that `T` is the *current* subclass of `Foo` from with `Foo`, then that it is not currently possible to guarantee that.  I've submitted a proposal to the Roslyn team to add a new type  constraint to deal with this issue.  See it here: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/4332  Please chime in there if you feel that is important.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a common implementation, then yes. If the implementation is different for various types, then no.

For a common implementation, simply put the common behavior in the abstract base class, as per Template Method pattern.

```
abstract class Foo<T>
{
    public void DoStuff(T obj)
    {
       ...implementation...
    }
}
```